# Amazon EC2 Install SSL certificate on Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have followed the [Amazon tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html) to install the SSL certificate on the EC2 instance. However at the end of procedure, I cannot start the HTTPD server.

My detailed steps:

1. Installed the module: sudo yum install -y mod24_ssl AND I tested with the local signed SSL certificate, it worked.
2. Generate myprivate.key and my.csr: openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myprivate.key -out my.csr
3. Submit my.csr to Startcom and get the certificate file: mycertificate.pem
4. Put the myprivate.key in the folder: /etc/pki/tls/private/
5. Put the mycertificate.pem in the folder: /etc/pki/tls/certs/
6. Change the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf: SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mycertificate.pem
7. Change the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCertificqteKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/myprivate.key

Note: I've deleted both localhost.key and localhost.crt. 
Was it due to the deletion of localhost.key file?

Comment: what do you get in the apache error log?